# How can I use OpenLDAP as the store for OpenAM under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, opensso

I realize there are a number of sources on how to get OpenLDAP set up under Ubuntu, or how to configure data stores for OpenAM (formerly OpenSSO). Some that seem most useful to me are:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8236370&postcount=1

https://blogs.oracle.com/indira/entry/using_openldap_as_user_data

Unfortunately, when I try to import the LDIF exported from the previous system where OpenSSO (actually Java Access Manager, but I'm hoping they're as interchangeable as they appear) was installed, I get the following error:

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #2 invalid per syntax
```

If I comment out some of the objectClass lines, I'll get down to another syntax error, which makes it seem to me like I'm missing a crucial schema. I've added the schema provided at the second link above, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

This page [ <s>http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-3320/ghlvi?a=view</s> (link dead) ] describes a list of LDIF files to import that it suggests are distributed with OpenSSO, but alas not all of them seem to be in the available downloads from ForgeRock (maintainers of OpenAM). [ http://www.forgerock.org/downloads.html ] Only the fam_* schema are there.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to what to attempt next. I don't have much experience with LDAP configuration, so it may be that I'm overlooking something quite obvious. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because I'm a new user, I wasn't allowed to post more than one link, so I removed all the http:// - sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2):

This error is either the objectclass value is not recognized, or the attribute syntax is invalid often due to extra spaces in the LDIF definition of the entry.

Comment: Thanks for answering here, too, @Ludo. :) I realized after I posted that it seemed more like a ServerFault question, so I created a better question there: http://serverfault.com/questions/195793/setting-up-openldap-for-opensso-openam-under-ubuntu